# What is the difference between AirPrint, Bonjour and Rendezvous?

Tags: ios, network, printing, bonjour

While know what AirPrint does, I am confused about what it is. It claims to be a bunch of technology standards used together such as mDNS, IPP and multicasting. However, the term Bonjour is also thrown around as well, which also appears to be based on the same technologies. What makes it even more confusing is that Bonjour is just a rebrand of Rendezvous.

Is AirPrint a rebrand of Bonjour, the same way Bonjour is a rebrand of Rendezvous, or is AirPrint distinct from Bonjour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AirPrint is the full protocol that allows a device to discover a printer and send a PDF over to it which is then printed.

Bonjour is the protocol that allows devices to discover each other and chat. AirPrint uses Bonjour.

A very rough and incorrect analogy is that AirPrint is to Bonjour, what an Internet Browser is to the Network connection.

Note: As PDF fully describes the pages to print, a traditional printer driver is not needed on the device.

Comment: Thanks.  So Bonjour is just Apple branding for zeroconfig, a general protocol for device discovery, while AirPrint builds upon to support printing on wireless devices.

Comment: My laserprinter uses Postscript internally. So if it were AirPrint enabled, it would be sent a pdf, which is based on Postscript.  Seems like PDF is a very format to send to printers, especially ones that don't have postscript.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Postscript is a general programming language that happens to be able to create printed output.  PDF is a subset of Postscript just for describing pages.

Comment: @ATL_DEV The printer will probably have a PDF-renderer built in regardless of what else it has.  I bought a tiny, used HP laser printer way back.  A firmware upgrade added AirPrint, and it had only PCL.

Comment: Does this mean AirPrint is not really based on open standards if it requires some PDF and or PostScript processing?  It's interesting how Apple and Adobe got back into bed together after their battles over TrueType and Flash.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Well.  Now would be a good time for you to study more instead of conjecturing :)  PDF is standardized for this very purpose and many render-to-pixels implementations exist (like the one in your favorite browser).   Postscript is not needed for that but MAY be supported by the printer as well.  The only reason Flash was a problem, was because it was not fitted to mobile devices, and Apple just were the first big one to walk away without looking back.

Comment: You gave me hope!  I have an over 20 year old LaserJet 4000n with build-in PostScript and a  610N JetDirect card that refuses to die. It's a beast to say the least! I've been struggling to make it AirPrint enabled using OpenWrt and a router, but gave up. Instead, I will instead upgrade to a JetDirect 635N which has Bonjour support. Hopefully, it may have AirPrint enabled or at least make it easier to enable. It's too bad there's no open firmware available for JetDirect.

Comment: @ATL_DEV That is quite unlikely to work.  The printer itself needs to support it.  Most printers these days support bonjour (because it makes them very easy to use with Macs).  In your shoes I would consider either a new printer, or look at whether HP has made an App for your device.

Answer (score 5):

First Rendezvous = Bonjour = unicast DNS

I forget why the name changed from Rendezvous, something about what Apple (used to) call it and what everyone else called it. It’s a server less DNS solution so devices can query locally, self-assemble, and discover services without needing a pre-configured DNS server / database.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS
- http://www.multicastdns.org/

AirPrint is a standard Wireless Printing protocol so that diverse printers all look like a standard printer, eliminating the need for specific drivers for specific printers. In the same way that LPR (Line Printer Protocol)is a printing protocol as well as IPP (Internet Printing Protocol). Here’s some Apple support / marketing information:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311 (AirPrint specifics)
- https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-reference-ios/intro-to-bonjour-apd0401947ff/web (Bonjour DNS)

Per wikipedia: "AirPrint is based on mDNS (Bonjour, more specifically) and Internet Printing Protocol (IPP)."(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_printing_protocols#Wireless_protocols)

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but how is AirPrint different from Bonjour?

Comment: @ATL_DEV AirPrint is the protocol used to send data to a printer discovered via Bonjour

Comment: There is also ZeroConf that is what everybody else calls Bonjour.

Comment: Jeez, I haven't heard *that* word in *years*

Comment: It appears that the Windows juggernaut meant that the world heads for uPNP instead of Zeroconf.